# Symfony 2.5.6 - UnexpectedTypeException being thrown in a custom form type

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following form type:

```
class GalleryImageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('thumb', new GalleryThumbnailImage(), array('label' => 'Thumbnail Image'))
            ->add('full', new GalleryFullSizeImage(), array('label' => 'Full Size Image'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'galleryImage';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'MajorProductions\SewingDiva\SiteBundle\Entity\GalleryImage'));
    }
}
```

And the following entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="GalleryImage", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 */
class GalleryImage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="GalleryThumbnailImage", mappedBy="galleryImage")
     */
    private $thumb;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="GalleryFullSizeImage", mappedBy="galleryImage")
     */
    private $full;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastModified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastModified;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return GalleryFullSizeImage
     */
    public function getFull()
    {
        return $this->full;
    }

    /**
     * @param GalleryFullSizeImage $full
     */
    public function setFull(Full $full)
    {
        $this->full = $full;
    }

    /**
     * @return GalleryThumbnailImage
     */
    public function getThumb()
    {
        return $this->thumb;
    }

    /**
     * @param GalleryThumbnailImage $thumb
     */
    public function setThumb(Thumb $thumb)
    {
        $this->thumb = $thumb;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getLastModified()
    {
        return $this->lastModified;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $lastModified
     */
    public function setLastModified(\DateTime $lastModified)
    {
        $this->lastModified = $lastModified;
    }
}

// ----

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="GalleryFullSizeImage", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 */
class GalleryFullSizeImage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="GalleryImage", inversedBy="full")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="galleryImageId", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $galleryImage;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\Image(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    private $tmp;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getGalleryImage()
    {
        return $this->galleryImage;
    }

    public function setGalleryImage(GalleryImage $galleryImage)
    {
        $this->galleryImage = $galleryImage;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir() . '/full';
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/gallery';
    }

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        // check if we have an old image path
        if (is_file($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->tmp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns file
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            $this->path = $this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->tmp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->tmp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->tmp = null;
        }

        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->id . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension()
        );

        $this->setFile(null);
        $this->galleryImage->setLastModified(new \DateTime(null));
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function storeFilenameForRemove()
    {
        $this->tmp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if (isset($this->tmp)) {
            unlink($this->tmp);
            $this->galleryImage->setLastModified(new \DateTime(null));
        }
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->id . '.' . $this->path;
    }
}

// ----

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="GalleryThumbnailImage", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_idx", columns={"id"})})
 */
class GalleryThumbnailImage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="GalleryImage", inversedBy="thumb")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="galleryImageId", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $galleryImage;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\Image(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    private $tmp;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getGalleryImage()
    {
        return $this->galleryImage;
    }

    public function setGalleryImage(GalleryImage $galleryImage)
    {
        $this->galleryImage = $galleryImage;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir() . '/thumbs';
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/gallery';
    }

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        // check if we have an old image path
        if (is_file($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->tmp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns file
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            $this->path = $this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->tmp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->tmp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->tmp = null;
        }

        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->id . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension()
        );

        $this->setFile(null);
        $this->galleryImage->setLastModified(new \DateTime(null));
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function storeFilenameForRemove()
    {
        $this->tmp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if (isset($this->tmp)) {
            unlink($this->tmp);
            $this->galleryImage->setLastModified(new \DateTime(null));
        }
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->id . '.' . $this->path;
    }
}
```

And when I attempt to view the form itself, I get the following error message from an `UnexpectedTypeException`:

> Expected argument of type "string or Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface", "MajorProductions\SewingDiva\SiteBundle\Entity\GalleryThumbnailImage" given

So, it's choking on the `FormBuilder` addition of my `GalleryThumbnailImage` field, thinking it should be backed by a string rather than that object.  I really don't know why it's doing that, however.  Could it be because I used namespace aliases in `GalleryImage` (`Thumb` in place of `GalleryThumbnailImage` and `Full` in place of `GalleryFullSizeImage`)?  Or am I missing something obvious?

---

EDIT: The problem remains even after creating form types for `GalleryFullSizeImage` and `GalleryThumbnailImage`:

```
namespace MajorProductions\SewingDiva\SiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class GalleryFullSizeImageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file', 'file');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'galleryFullSizeImage';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'MajorProductions\SewingDiva\SiteBundle\Entity\GalleryFullSizeImage'));
    }
}

// ----

namespace MajorProductions\SewingDiva\SiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class GalleryThumbnailImageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file', 'file');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'galleryThumbnailImage';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'MajorProductions\SewingDiva\SiteBundle\Entity\GalleryThumbnailImage'));
    }
}
```

Note that where `// ----` is written in my code, that represents the end of one file and the beginning of another.  Given the length of my entity code with all of the Doctrine annotations, I figured I'd save some vertical space by putting the code of individual classes in the same code blocks here.

Comment: You can't just put any class as a form type. How Symfony2 should know how to handle / submit / render this element? You need to make a form type which encapsulates basic primitive information about your entity and then convert that data to a full object in your PHP code.

Comment: Since these are child entities (`GalleryImage` is essentially a container for the other two), I'm assuming you mean that I need to create a form type for each of them as well.

Comment: Problem remains.  See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use:

```
$builder
    ->add('thumb', new GalleryThumbnailImage(), array('label' => 'Thumbnail Image'))
    ->add('full', new GalleryFullSizeImage(), array('label' => 'Full Size Image'));
```

Let's recall what the arguments of `FormBuilder#add()` are: `public function add($child, $type = null, array $options = array())`. Instead of `$type`, you seem to pass an entity. The classes you want to pass here are `GalleryThumbnailImageType` and `GalleryFullSizeImageType`. These classes do implement `FormTypeInterface`, so everything is ok!

The code you need to use:

```
$builder
    ->add('thumb', new GalleryThumbnailImageType(), array('label' => 'Thumbnail Image'))
    ->add('full', new GalleryFullSizeImageType(), array('label' => 'Full Size Image'));
```

Comment: What's really sad is that I'm basing this off of another project that has a similar parent->child setup with file handling, and it has the form type right there.  I was staring at it all night last night, but didn't notice it.  Ugh.  Thanks for the help :)